# problem in DataTextField with non simple return value

Tags: asp.net, datatextfield

I know that the syntax for using DataTextField is:

```
VA.DataTextField = "nameofcolum"
```

but if my request is not simple that means my request returns the result in a column which not exist in this case. What I should to affect to DataTextField?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you're looking for here without more information.

If your result set does not contain the column you need, **change your result set** - alter your query. If you need your datatextfield as a combination of columns, you can iterate through the result set and build the text string based on the column values and assign it as the display value.

Comment: i don't understand your proposition
this is my query :
SELECT V.DESIGNATION+'-->'+V1.DESIGNATION as Voyages FROM VILLES AS V, VILLES AS V1, VOYAGES AS VO WHERE VO.VIL_ID=V.ID And VO.VIL2_ID=V1.ID
the execution of this query in access displays in a colum "Expr1000"
this colum not exist in my table so i try this :
DataTextField = Expr1000 but not working
can you more explain your proposition

Comment: Might be a problem trying to alias your column the same name as your table name. Try changing **SELECT V.DESIGNATION+'-->'+V1.DESIGNATION as Voyages** to **SELECT V.DESIGNATION+'-->'+V1.DESIGNATION as Designation** or something like that.